# MultiList/MultiDropdownList not showing or throwing errors in React

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

I have been struggling to get some of the faceted search options working in ReactiveSearch/ReactiveBase.

When trying to get the MultiList or MultiDropdownList working, nothing shows where it should, and there are no error messages in Dev Tools whatsoever.

The SingleRange section works perfectly fine, but I can't get any of the text MultiList features working.

Here is my entire 'render' section, just in-case there is something simple that I have missed:

```
render() {
    return (
        <ReactiveBase
            app="properties"
            url="http://<el-server-ip>:9200">
            <CategorySearch
                    componentId="searchbox"
                    dataField={["PropertyType","County"]}
                    categoryField="Country"
                    autoSuggest={true}
                    fuzziness={0}
                    queryFormat="and"
                    placeholder="Search for properties"
            />
            <SingleRange
                    componentId="ratingsfilter"
                    title="Filter by ratings"
                    dataField="Price_Unformatted"
                    data={[
                        {"start": 0, "end": 500000, "label": "0 - 500k"},
                        {"start": 500000, "end": 1000000, "label": "500k - 1m"},
                        {"start": 1000000, "end": 10000000, "label": "1m - 10m"},
                        {"start": 0, "end": 1000000000000, "label": "10m+"},
                    ]}
                />
            <MultiList
              componentId="TypeSensor"
              dataField="PropertyType.raw"
              title="Type"
            />
                <ResultCard
                    componentId="result"
                    title="Results"
                    dataField="PropertyType"
                    from={0}
                    size={15}
                    pagination={true}
                    react={{
                        and: ["searchbox", "ratingsfilter","TypeSensor"]
                    }}
                    onData={(res) => {
                        return {
                            image: res.PicNumber,
                            title: res.PropertyType,
                            description: res.Description_EN.substr(0,100)
                        }
                    }}
            />
        </ReactiveBase>
    );
}
```

And to give you an idea of the sort of data that I am working with, just in-case there is a type mismatch causing the error:

```
"_source": {
                "objectID": 211956,
                "Continent": "Europe",
                "Country": "France",
                "County": "Aude ",
                "Location": "Carcassonne",
                "Area": null,
                "Price": "EUR 890,000",
                "Price_Unformatted": 890000,
                "PropertyType": "Chateau",
                "Bedrooms": 9,
                "Bathrooms": 6,
                "PicNumber": "file.jpg",
                "Description_EN": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...",
                "Currency": "EUR",
            }
```

Is there any way of getting some sort of output/error message from React or ReactiveSearch in this case, so that I can accurately see what the issue is?

I have seen errors previously, though those were mostly syntax.

Comment: How does your mapping look like?

Comment: Good idea, I have checked all of the mappings and they correspond to a chunk of data that I checked. Aka, it should all work without an issue.

Comment: I could tell more from the mappings :) The `dataField` for `MultiList` should allow aggregations (eg - keyword in ES5), could be an issue with that.

Comment: Hi there, I've uploaded the mappings here: https://jsonblob.com/52568041-7b79-11e8-a427-5be7ca0d11bc   I hope this is alright.

Comment: Thanks, could you check my answer. I think it should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `MultiList` has to run aggregations on the `dataField` provided. From the [mappings](https://jsonblob.com/52568041-7b79-11e8-a427-5be7ca0d11bc) you should use the `keyword` type so an aggregation can be run on it. So the if you update the multifield to `.keyword` instead of `.raw` here it should work:

```
<MultiList
  componentId="TypeSensor"
  dataField="PropertyType.keyword"
  title="Type"
/>
```